# One to Many relationship with Spring Data JPA, @Entity type not recognized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, relationship, one-to-many

I am trying to create a unidirectional one to many relationship in Spring Boot app. I have Users and Devices. One user can have multiple devices.
I am working with microservices, so I have one module for User and one module for Device.
This is my User class

```
package com.demo.user.entity;

import com.demo.device.entity.Device;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ud_fk",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Device> devices;

    public List<Device> getDevices() {
        return devices;
    }

    public void setDevices(List<Device> devices) {
        this.devices = devices;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

And this is my Device class

```
package com.demo.device.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String address;
    private int consumption;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getConsumption() {
        return consumption;
    }

    public void setConsumption(int consumption) {
        this.consumption = consumption;
    }
}
```

**This is the error i get when i try to create that one to many relationship.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'com.demo.user.entity.User.devices' targets the type 'com.demo.device.entity.Device' which is not an '@Entity' type
```

I don't understand why Device is not recognized as @Entity, as I have that annotation there...
Please help!

This is my pom.xml file as well

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There is no problem in Your code. Try to invalidate cache of your IDE, or reimport project to load all dependencies again. As a sidenote, Your unidirectional OneToMany mapping [is not a best practice](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/).

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. Maybe Spring was not able to find your entities. Try setting `EntityScan` in your main, or some config file to see if the problem persists, and also add required `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor` from lombok.

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.baeldung.demopackage")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityScanDemo {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to add EntityScan and to reimport project, but I get the same error..

Comment: i added my pom.xml file too, maybe there is a problem..

Comment: try adding `import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;` . And you could also remove the hibernate dependency

Comment: updated my answer with suggested changes